# Django {% url %} when urls with parameters like: url(r'^foo/<parameter>/$', include(some.urls))

Tags: python, django, django-templates

i don't find any solution, how to get the url in template with the following configuration (using Django1.3):

*urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^/foo/(?P<parameter>\d+)/$', include('bar.urls'), name='foo-url'),
    )
```

Included url-conf:

*bar.urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^/bar/$', 'bar.views.index'),
    url(r'^/bar/(?P<parameter2>\d+)/$', 'bar.views.detail', name='bar-url'),
    )
```

*bar.views.py*

```
def detail(request, parameter, parameter2):
    obj1 = Foo.objects.get(id=parameter)
    obj2 = Bar.objects.get(id=parameter2)
```

Now I try to get the url in template with:

```
{% url bar-url parameter=1 parameter2=2 %}
```

I expect to get: **/bar/1/foo/2/**

Is it posible to use in this case the {% url %}?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can get your url like this:-

```
{% url 'bar-url' 1 2 %}
```

But note that your url configuration should actually be like this:-

*urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^/foo/(?P<parameter>\d+)/, include('bar.urls')),
)
```

*bar.urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^/bar/$, 'bar.views.index'),
    url(r'^/bar/(?P<parameter2>\d+)/$, 'bar.views.detail', name='bar-url'),
)
```

There is no `foo-url` unless you specifically map:-

*urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^/foo/(?P<parameter>\d+)/$, 'another.views.foo', name='foo'),
    url(r'^/foo/(?P<parameter>\d+)/, include('bar.urls')),
)
```

Note that `$` means the end of the regular expression.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I got it working now. I make some mistakes when setting the parameter in the url-tag. I use version 1.3, therefor `{% url bar-url 1 2 %}` works.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I usually set namespace for included urls to simplify the process:

in root urlpatterns

> url(r'^articles/', include('articles.urls', namespace='articles')),

in articles/urls.py

> url(r'^(\d+)/$', 'read', name='read'),
>
> url(r'^publish/$', 'publish', name='publish'),

And then in your template you can simply type:

> {% url articles:read 1 %}
>
> ## or
>
> {% url articles:publish %}

More about this [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces).

Comment: I'm trying to use namespaces, but it seems not to work with a parameter before the included urls.py. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788062/django-url-parameters-before-include-url-with-namespace