# django url parameters before include url with namespace

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

In my last question I asked how to get urls working for parameter before included urls.py and it worked.
[Django {% url %} when urls with parameters like: url(r'^foo/<parameter>/$', include(some.urls))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521172/django-url-when-urls-with-parameters-like-urlrfoo-parameter-incl)

Now I want to use the same included urls.py **with namespaces**.

*urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^/foo/(?P<parameter_1>\d+)/', include('bar.urls', namespace='foo', app_name='foo')),
    )
```

*bar.urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^/bar/$', 'bar.views.index', name='bar'),
    url(r'^/bar/(?P<parameter_2>\d+)/$', 'bar.views.detail', name='bar_detail'),
    )
```

To get the url in template I use:

```
1. {% url foo:bar parameter_1=1 %} or {% url for:bar 1 %}
2. {% url foo:bar_detail parameter_1=1 parameter_2=1 %} or {% url foo:bar_detail 1 1 %}
```

I expect to get the url: 1. `/foo/1/bar/` and 2. `/foo/1/bar/1` but it does not work.

Interesting: if I call:

```
1. {% url foo:bar %}
2. {% url foo:bar_detail parameter_2=1 %} or {% url foo:bar_detail 1 %}
```

I get the urls:
1. `/foo/(?P<parameter_1>%5Cd+)/bar/` and
2. `/foo/(?P<parameter_1>%5d+)/bar/1`

My question: Did i have a fault in my code or is the code not useful for, what i want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I searched again and found the fault. There's a bug in the `/django/core/urlresolvers.py`.

I found the ticket at https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11559#no1.

To fix the problem you have to replace the `/django/core/urlresolvers.py` with the changed file from https://github.com/django/django/commit/02dcbe3317.

After restarting the def-server with `python manage.py runserver` the url-tags are resolved correct. I get `/foo/1/bar/` from `{% url foo:bar 1 %}` instead of `/foo/(?P<parameter_1>%5Cd+)/bar/`.

Comment: Interesting! I had the same problem and found out it was a bug in django's reverse method. Unfortunately, my project was using a (painfully) old version of Django (1.3). I ended up changing the url structure so parent urlconf didn't capture any parameters. But do you know a way to solve this, which doesn't imply updating to the newest django version? (Which i guess is something i will ultimately end up doing)