# django: using url parameters and url namespacing simultaneously

Tags: django

I have a namespaced URL...

```
 url(r'^(?P<page_lang>\w+)/forum/', include('djangobb_forum.urls', namespace='djangobb')),
```

which then goes through to another urls.py in an app...

```
url(r'^$', forum_views.index, name='index'),
```

but I am getting an error when it tries to reverse lookup by the namespace.

```
<a href="{% url 'djangobb:forum_posts_feed' %}">
```

I cannot see what is causing this, and I tried to use this fix...

[django url parameters before include url with namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788062/django-url-parameters-before-include-url-with-namespace)

but I had no luck, any ideas?

EDIT:

I have verfied that it is being cause by the parameter being passed along with the namespace, because I replaced it with something static and the problem went away, how can I make this work?

EDIT2:

error:

```
Reverse for 'forum_posts_feed' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'(?P<page_lang>\\w+)/forum/feeds/posts/$']
```

if i try to add "page_lang" to the url template tag, the error changes to this...

```
Reverse for 'forum_posts_feed' with arguments '(<SiteLanguage: SiteLanguage object>,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'(?P<page_lang>\\w+)/forum/feeds/posts/$']
```

Comment: You don't pass `parameter` to your url, It's impossible to resolve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems odd that you can't see what's causing this, since you obviously know it's to do with the parameter. Where do you think that value is going to come from? You need to pass it in your url tag:

```
<a href='{% url "myname:index" parameter=value %}'>
```

Comment: but why wouldn't that parameter be passed through the urls, like it is everywhere else? when i try to do this I get the same failure

Comment: Er, what? I don't understand your comment at all. The parameter *is* passed to your view, like any other parameter; it's up to you to actually do something with it.

Comment: what I meant is that the parameter should be captured from the url, right? those parameters are captured from the url regex and the passed into the view. I think I meant to say captured instead of passed. Does that make more sense?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It *is* captured. It goes into your view as a parameter. What makes you think that's not happening?

Comment: I don't think it doesn't. I think I just misspoke and made it unclear. Even when I pass the argument in my url (parameter=value) I still get a Reverse lookup not found. What can I do to make my problem clearer?

Comment: You should show the new error you're getting. Are you passing `parameter` from the view into the template?

Comment: added edits to the main post and changed the urls to my actual code, rather than a simplified version

Comment: Well it seems that the thing you're passing as `page_lang` in the view is a SiteLanguage object, rather than the slug you're originally getting in the URL. You need to use the slug.