# Django URL with parameter not working with include

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I am trying to pass a parameter to a url before my include statement. I think my problem should be [similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788062/django-url-parameters-before-include-url-with-namespace), but I can't figure out why mine isn't working. I get the error `NoReverseMatch at /womens/ Reverse for 'shampoo' with arguments '('womens',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<gender>womens|mens)/items/shampoo/$']`

```
*config.urls*
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'(?P<gender>womens|mens)/items/$, include('items.urls')),
    ...
]
```

```
*items.urls*
urlpatterns = [
    path('shampoo', views.shampoo, name='shampoo'),
    path('soap', views.soap, name='soap'),
    ...
]
```

```
{% url 'items:shampoo' gender='male' %}
```

I expect to get `male/items/shampoo`, but it doesn't work. Despite this, I can still manually go to `male/items/shampoo`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work when you do it manually like `male/items/shampoo`, but as it is giving a NoReverseMatch error, Django is not able to find a matching URL pattern that you provided which included the parameters.

After looking into this for some time, something like this might be happening when you use `{% url 'items:shampoo' gender='male' %}`
Assuming you are running this on your localhost, you expect the URL to look like `male/items/shampoo`
This url says, look into male section, among items show shampoo.
But you are passing the parameter in the wrong place. `{% url 'items:shampoo' gender='male' %}` means that the parameter `male` is passed to a url which has a namespace of `shampoo`. The URL with the namespace of `shampoo` does not accept any parameters.

Maybe try changing your code as follows.

```
*config.urls*
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^$', include('items.urls')),
    ...
]
```

```
from django.conf.urls import url, path
*items.urls*
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<gender>\w+)/items/shampoo/$', views.shampoo, name='shampoo'),
    path('soap', views.soap, name='soap'),
    ...
]
```